# Using Bluebird Promises in Node.JS with 2 async operations

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have a scenario where I need to get the records from MySQL database and update in redis cache and close the MySQL and redis connection.

Steps:

1. Open MySQL connection
2. Get records from MySQL database on success
3. Update Redis cache on success from MySQL Query Result
4. Close the MySQL db connection.

I am trying to do using Bluebird promises but not getting appropriate results.

Problem in below code is **done** is getting called initially and even in **processBreakingNewsData** function which supposed to be executed last.

Please correct me in the places where I have done mistake

Below is my node.js code

**constants.js file**

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

module.exports = {
  getRedisConnection: function () {
    return require("redis").createClient(6379, 'XXXX', { auth_pass: 'XXXX' });
  },
  getMySqlConnection: function () {
    var conObj = { host: "localhost", user: "root", password: "", database: "deccan" };

    var connection = require("mysql").createConnection(conObj);

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      connection.connect(function (error) { 
        if (error)
          reject(error);
        else
          resolve(connection);
      });
    });       
  }
};
```

**testing.js file**

```
var constants = require("./constants.js");
var Promise = require('bluebird');

constants.getMySqlConnection().then(processBreakingNewsData)
.catch(function (e) {
  console.log("Error : " + e);
}).done(function () {
  console.log("Finished");
});

function processBreakingNewsData(connection) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    connection.query("select id, text, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as 'created_at' from breakingnews;", function (error, results) {
      connection.end();

      if (error)
        reject(error);
      else
        resolve(results);
    });

  }).then(function (results) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      var value = "";

      if (results.length > 0)
        value = JSON.stringify(results);

      var client = constants.getRedisConnection();

      client.set("bnews", value, function (err, reply) {
        if (err)
          reject(new Error("Error during Update of BreakingNews : " + err));
        else
          resolve(reply);
      });
    });           
  }).catch(function (e) {
    console.log("Error during Update of BreakingNews : " + e);

  }).done(function (result) {
    console.log("Breaking News Updated in Redis.");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 2 issues here :

1. **`then` always return a promise**

`.then` always returns a promise. If you don't return one yourself, a resolved promise is created with the return value. That's what happens here : the `.then` in `processBreakingNewsData` immediatly returns a resolved promise, which then executes your done callback.

To avoid this, you need to explicitly return an ongoing promise :

```
function processBreakingNewsData(connection)
{
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) 
    {
        // ...
    }).then(function (results) 
    {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            // ...
```

2. **`done` does not return a promise**

Your last `done` handler does not return a promise, which means the entire `processBreakingNewsData` does not return a promise. So, again, the calling `then` returns immediately with a resolved promise.

**Never use done. This is from the documentation :**

```
.done(
    [function(any value) fulfilledHandler],
    [function(any error) rejectedHandler]
) -> undefined
```

> The use
>   of this method is heavily discouraged and it only exists for
>   historical reasons.

You can safely replace `done` by `then` here, since you catch errors beforehand.

Comment: how can I handle the first 'then' -> constants.getMySqlConnection().then(processBreakingNewsData)

Comment: @Sharath I don't see an issue here, you pass a function returning a promise so it should be ok. What unexpected behavior do you encounter ?

Comment: I have updated the source code with the changes you mentioned. Now the result is done block is executed initially itself and then Breaking News Updated in Redis. is printed. But actually Finished should have been last statement to be executed.

I mean should I put the processBreakingNewsData function inside a promise ?

Comment: @Sharath there is an issue with the `done` function in bluebird : it doesn't return a promise like `then`. Usage of `done` is discouraged. I have updated my answer.